# Plaid API and Spring Boot - Problem with making an API call

Tags: java, spring-boot, plaid, plaidml

This may seem like a very specific question, however I am sure that the problem I am running into can be abstracted into a situation that can occur when working with any API or Spring Boot in general.

I am using Plaid's API for retrieving dummy information from a dummy bank account to work with a budgeting app I am working on. As I am trying to make a get request to retrieve data, I am running into an IllegalArgumentException of type "Unexpected value "signal". I am unsure why this is, and I will attach a screenshot below to illustrate the API's methods and the terminal output. This description is rather straightforward, but I can provide more description if needed, or seek the Plaid manual to understand the API's use as I am doing here, albeit it seems pretty obvious with its meaning method names. Thanks!

I have tried reading the documentation and seeking for the official repository where Plaid offers Java bindings and testing of its features. Moreover, I have tried debugging but I am unable to pinpoint where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with the Plaid client library you're using being out of sync with the actual API -- the API is sending a value of "signal" but the client library isn't expecting it. Try updating to the latest version of the plaid-java client library and trying again. If that doesn't fix it, go ahead and file a Plaid support ticket. (This should never happen, BTW, but I think in this particular case there's a misconfiguration of either a field in the API or a field in the client library.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with plaid-java version 9.0.0 which is offered in Plaid's quickstart guide. Updating to 18.0.0 resolved it